# Missing relations in Designer of Reporting Tool List & Label using SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, listlabel

I'm currently testing various reporting tools and came across to List & Label from Combit, which makes a very solid impression. As part of a PoC, I first integrated it into a simple C# Winforms application and attached a SQL Server database.

```
...
using(ListLabel myLL = new ListLabel())
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
    myLL.DataSource = new SqlConnectionDataProvider(connection);
    myLL.Design();
}
...
```

However, I don't understand why with the data structure in the designer I can't then also see the relational structure in/from the database.... all relations seem to be just ignored. I can only see all tables at the root level - even though they are a relation in the SQL Server database.

Couldn't find any information for this so far unfortunately - ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's all there usually. You should be able to see the full structure, as soon as you add a report container:

[image: Data Source Selection for Table]

This way, you can add e.g. "Order Details" either as a sub element of the customers (like shown in the screenshot) or as a top level element (if I had selected it from the root of the list).

The field tree on the other hand just shows the available tables with their contents ("fields"). As each table may appear in different levels of the hierarchy, it's only added once to the tree, while the hierarchy is defined when adding a new table.

One exception from this rule is the 1:1 related identifiers of parent tables. As it might well be required to print e.g. Customer data related to an order line in a "Orders" table, you cann access them directly from the field tree:

[image: Field Tree with 1:1 Relation]

Thus, you actually *do* see the relations there, albeit in reverse order. While this might seem confusing at first it really makes sense once you get your head around the concept.

Comment: Thank your for that detailed clarification. In the first look at the Designer it is a little bit confusing, because it seems ignoring the relations. But the hint to use the report container open my eyes. I'll give it a try. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, it's all too tempting to just open the tree and see the relational structure from there. However, the approach we have chosen is quite flexible in terms of different and especially very complex data sources with loads of tables and relations. This would quickly render the Designer unusable otherwise.